# Machine Learning over distributed operating system

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I want to implement Distributed operating system mutual exclusion using Machine learning algorithms but I am not getting dataset anywhere to perform.
Is there anyway i can get the required dataset?
I already tried UCI and amazon public dataset site.

Comment: Try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/